# Не выполняется задача Hangfire

Tags: asp.net-core-mvc, hangfire

Есть сайт на ASP.Net 6.0. В Configure startyp.cs создаётся класс-инициализатор

```
public static class SiteInit
{
    private static void AddTasks (IServiceProvider serviceProvider, [NotNull] IConfiguration configuration)
        {
            //Получаю DependencyIjector
            serviceProvider = serviceProvider.CreateScope().ServiceProvider;
            //Провожу инъекцию аккаунта
            AccountManager account = serviceProvider.GetRequiredService<AccountManager>();

            byte.TryParse(configuration["accountsettings:newbieexceededhours"], out byte hourstodelete);

        /* To-Do после теста отключить на Dayly */
        RecurringJob.AddOrUpdate(() => NewbieDeleterTask.Execute(account, hourstodelete), Cron.Hourly);
    }
    public static void InitSite (IServiceProvider service,[NotNull] IConfiguration configuration)
    {
        AddTasks(service, configuration);
    }
}
```

Его задача инициализировать задачу, данную в классе:

```
/// <summary>
/// Задача удаления новичков после n часов
/// </summary>
public static class NewbieDeleterTask
{
    private static async Task ExecuteAsync ([NotNull] AccountManager account, byte hours = 36)
    {
        //Получение текущей даты
        DateTime dateTime = DateTime.UtcNow;

        //Получение списока пользователей с неподтверждённым email
        IEnumerable<MyUser> notConfirmedUsers = account.GetAllUsers().Where(usr => !usr.EmailConfirmed);

        //Список "просроченных" пользователей
        // ReSharper disable once CollectionNeverQueried.Local
        List<MyUser> overdueUsers = new();

        //Получаем список просрочек
        foreach (MyUser user in notConfirmedUsers)
        {
            if (await account.IsUserInRoleAsync(user, "newbie") && user.DateOfRegister.AddHours(hours).CompareTo(dateTime) <= 0)
                overdueUsers.Add(user);
        }

        //Удаляем пользователей
        foreach (MyUser user in overdueUsers)
            await account.DeleteUserAsync(user);
    }

    public static void Execute([NotNull] AccountManager account, byte hours = 36) =>
        ExecuteAsync(account, hours).GetAwaiter().GetResult();
}
```

Сам AccountManager -- обёртка класса usermanager и rolemanager.

В общем, Hangfire ругается так:

```
warn: Hangfire.AutomaticRetryAttribute[0]
      Failed to process the job '10004': an exception occurred. Retry attempt 1 of 10 will be performed in 00:00:21.
      System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
         at rnrmm.Platform.AccountManager.GetAllUsers() in E:\WebSites\rnrmm_ru\rnrmm_ru\Platform\AccountManager.cs:line 69
         at rnrmm.Tasks.NewbieDeleterTask.ExecuteAsync(AccountManager account, Byte hours) in E:\WebSites\rnrmm_ru\rnrmm_ru\Tasks\NewbieDeleterTask.cs:line 25
         at rnrmm.Tasks.NewbieDeleterTask.Execute(AccountManager account, Byte hours) in E:\WebSites\rnrmm_ru\rnrmm_ru\Tasks\NewbieDeleterTask.cs:line 44
warn: Hangfire.AutomaticRetryAttribute[0]
      Failed to process the job '10004': an exception occurred. Retry attempt 2 of 10 will be performed in 00:00:24.
      System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
         at rnrmm.Platform.AccountManager.GetAllUsers() in E:\WebSites\rnrmm_ru\rnrmm_ru\Platform\AccountManager.cs:line 69
         at rnrmm.Tasks.NewbieDeleterTask.ExecuteAsync(AccountManager account, Byte hours) in E:\WebSites\rnrmm_ru\rnrmm_ru\Tasks\NewbieDeleterTask.cs:line 25
         at rnrmm.Tasks.NewbieDeleterTask.Execute(AccountManager account, Byte hours) in E:\WebSites\rnrmm_ru\rnrmm_ru\Tasks\NewbieDeleterTask.cs:line 44
```

Сама функция **GetAllUsers** выглядит так:

```
public List<MyUser> GetAllUsers ()
    {
        IQueryable<MyUser> usersQuery = usermanager.Users;
        return usersQuery.ToList();
    }
```

Что не так? И почему она не получает пользователей (на сайте их 3)!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Проблема решается просто: нужно static-класс NewbieDeleterTask превратить в сервис с нормальной инъекцией, добавить его в **startup**:

```
services.TryAddScoped<NewbieDeleterTask>();
```

а затем создать в нужном месте задачу:

```
RecurringJob.AddOrUpdate<NewbieDeleterTask>(x => x.Execute(), Cron.Hourly);
```